# Input.value creates a weird delay in my console.log

Tags: javascript, html, textinput

I have a text input on the page. I'm trying to make it so that when I type characters into the input, it triggers #fourChord's text to change. Console.log is responding, but the first input character is ignored. If I enter an "a" into the text box nothing shows up in the console until I enter "aa", which shows up as "a". If I enter "aba", console logs "ab". "abab" becomes "aba" etc. How do I make it so this doesn't delay my first input?

```
<div class="container square">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="big">1-4-5</p>  
        <p class="toHide">Chord Progression</p>
        <p class="toHide">Calculator</p>
        <p class="errorMessage hide">Sorry! That chord does not exist!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">   
        <input class="col-sm-12" id="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter root chord">
        </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-around">
            <div id="fourChord" class="col-sm-4">4</div>
            <div id="fiveChord" class="col-sm-4">5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




input.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    console.log(input.value);
    fourChord.textContent = input.value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Keypress event happens before the input change. that's why it's always ignoring the last entered value,

> `keypress` events are fired before the new character is added to the input.
>   So the first keypress event is fired before the first character is added, while the input is still empty.
>   If you check the console you will see an empty line in console before you see value in input.
>   For example if you type `1` initially you will see an blank line in console, then type a different character, at that point you will see it is showing `1`.

You could use `input` or `keyup` event to get the updated value.

**Example with input event:**

```js
let input = document.getElementById("input");
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
    console.log(this.value);
    fourChord.textContent = this.value;
});
```

```html
<div class="container square">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="big">1-4-5</p>
        <p class="toHide">Chord Progression</p>
        <p class="toHide">Calculator</p>
        <p class="errorMessage hide">Sorry! That chord does not exist!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input class="col-sm-12" id="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter root chord">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-around">
            <div id="fourChord" class="col-sm-4">4</div>
            <div id="fiveChord" class="col-sm-4">5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```